# Syntax to transfer from remote to local scp by leapfrogging onto another host?

Tags: scp, remote, file-transfer

I am trying to copy files from a remote server to my local server, however, my remote server first requires me to connect to an intermediate host and then leapfrog onto the actual server from there. I am wondering how would I go about copying files from my remote server to my local machine with the scp command using this leapfrogging technique?

So first I have to connect to intermediate server, then from there I want to connect to my actual server.

Answer (score 3):

With modern versions of ssh this is very easy using the concept of a `ProxyJump` at least if you have keys set up.

Let us call the 3 machines L, I, and R (for local, intermediate, and remote). Assume to start with that the usernames are all the same.

The command required is then

```
scp -oProxyJump=I R:remote_file localfile
```

If the usernames are different then replace I with `user@I` and R with `user@R`.

If you are using ssh, the command would be:

```
ssh -J [user@]I [user@]R
```

Comment: The configuration parameter is named `ProxyJump` and is invoked when using 'ssh' by the `-J [<user>@]<destination>` flag. The scp command is slightly differnet, as it makes use of the `-oProxyJump=[<user>@]<destination>` syntax. Or at least that's what happens (and what the manual pages say) on the two machines where I tested this solution...

Comment: So JumpProxy does not work (gives error: bad configuration option jump proxy). So do I just switch JumpProxy with ProxyJump?

Comment: @skidjoe That would be it... I edited the earlier answer, so hopefully it will be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I'm looking to download a whole file/folder, do I just add -r before the R:remote_file or right after the scp?

Comment: I would use it right after the scp, just to make it more readable in your history (if you ever need to use it again...), so: `scp -r -oProxyJump=I R:remote_dir ./local_dir`

Comment: Thanks for the corrections JumpProxy -> ProxyJump.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing your ssh configuration to include a proxy. scp uses ssh for remote connections so just editing the ssh config should work. Use your "intermediate server" as the proxy.

Add something like this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host target.machine
  User          targetuser
  HostName      target.machine
  ProxyCommand  ssh proxyuser@proxy.machine nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Then just use `scp` as if you are connecting directly to the remote server.

To give credit where it's due, I took this from [here](https://superuser.com/a/320438).